# How to apply compression (e.g. LZW) when exporting a map from QGIS composer to TIF?

Tags: qgis, export, image, geotiff-tiff, compression

```
QGIS > Composer > Export as image > *.TIF
```

I need to apply lossless compression (e.g. LZW or ZIP), when exporting a map from QGIS (v2.18) composer to TIF image. This settings are missing in the export dialog. Where/How can I set it up?

(I know that I can export and re-save with external software like Imagemagick, or export to PNG and re-save in external software... this is just an unnecessary step).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is currently supported.

I usually export from Print Composer and make sure a world file is generated.
Go to Composition tab and select "Save world file".

With the world file, you can then bring the tiff back into qgis and when it's in the layer list you can right-click it and save-as.

From the save-as window you can choose the compression options you want.

Comment: Thanks @SaultDon. I also found a 3 years [old post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123585/save-map-in-raster-format-from-qgis-using-compression) with similar answer. That's a pitty.

Comment: @Juraj maybe check https://issues.qgis.org/issues to see if there is already a feature request to get this started - if not consider adding one!